# Групповые селекторы с атрибутами в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как обратиться к группе элементов в jQuery в рамках одной функции?
Например к ссылке:

```
a[href^="page-1.html#"]
```

Вот этот синтаксис не работает у меня:

```
$('a[href^="page-1.html#"]', 'a[href^="page-2.html#"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас запятая между кавычками, а нужно внутри.

```js
$('a[href^="page-1.html#"], a[href^="page-2.html#"]').click(function() {
  alert('Нажал');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="page-1.html#">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="page-2.html#">Ссылка 2</a>
```